# Approach to or for?

Tags: grammar, orthography

My sentence:
---The exploitation of natural and ecofriendly resources could be an alternative approach to creating a sustainable environment.

Is the preposition correct or should I rearrange the sentence?

Comment: see:  [approach (noun) B2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/approach)

Comment: I'd steer of exploitation no matter how well-intended. Also, not sure how wholesome resources are an *alternative* to sustainablity.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+approach+%2A+creating&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Can%20approach%20%2A%20creating%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20approach%20to%20creating%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20approach%20for%20creating%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20approach%20of%20creating%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Can%20approach%20*%20creating%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20approach%20to%20creating%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20approach%20for%20creating%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20approach%20of%20creating%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***to*** is most common (followed by ***for***, then ***of***).

Answer (score 1):

An “approach for” would refer to the subject making an approach. “Here is the best approach for you”. An “approach to” refers to the object to be approached. “Here is the best approach to your problem”. Your preposition is correct, because “creating an environment” is an object of ones efforts.